# Unable to install Pydev through Eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

I am unable to install PyDevthrough Eclipse 3.7.2 using the "Install New Software" menu option. I am running ubuntu 12.04 and the error I get starts

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile,
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.6.0.201406232321.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8822024852687497909.jar
```

.....

I have tried
  1) Unchecking the "Check all updates during install to find required software" box
  2) Updating the OS
  3) Reinstalling Eclipse
  4) Repeating the install at different times (over about 3 weeks)

I am working with the PyDev adnd Pydev Extensions website http://pydev.org/updates

Any idea. Should upgrade my ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. As in http://pydev.org/download.html, PyDev now requires Eclipse 3.8 onwards (mostly this is due to an issue in Eclipse itself failing to recognize the maven created PyDev update site -- which is fixed in Eclipse 3.8).